# missing script error on npm start command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I'm trying to start my react app
I deleted my package.json, node_modules and package-lock.json

I installed them back and when i try running npm start
I get the error

```
freduah@freduah:~/react-kempinski$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/freduah/.npm/_logs/2020-10-28T17_28_21_894Z-debug.log
freduah@freduah:~/react-kempinski$
```

The error is quite clear but yet i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your app with `create-react-app` check if have these lines in your `package.json` in `scripts` section.

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Try `npm run start` instead

Answer (score 1):

Check Your package.json file. In this file, You should see the `scripts` section.
The correct scripts should be something like this.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js", // The way to your start.js script
    "build": "node scripts/build.js", // The way to your build.js script
    "test": "node scripts/test.js" // The way to your test.js script
  },
```